# Angular 6 with Material, click event not working properly

Tags: angular, forms, click, angular-material

I am developing a simple Angular6-based form and want to create an input field similar to the ones I used at AWS.

This is snipper of the code I have:

```html
 <mat-form-field class="full-width">
     <input matInput [(ngModel)]="enteredText" type="text" (keyup.enter)="addToArray()" name="text">
 </mat-form-field>
```

And after comes my array of texts already added:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let text of textArray; let i = index">
        <span> {{ text }} </span>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteTextFromArray(i)"><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have an `enteredText` model as well as `textArray`.

Here is the `addToArray()` funtion:

```ts
addToArray() {
    this.textArray.push(this.enteredText);
    this.enteredText= '';
}
```

Here is the `deleteTextFromArray` function:

```ts
deleteTextFromArray(index) {
  this.textArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The problem I have is that I am not able to insert more than 1 element into the array. For some reason after the first element, each insertion triggers my delete function. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you put the `addToArray()` function too ?

Comment: Added the function

Comment: @AGoranov I've created the stackblitz and it is working fine, still what is the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1zfpe3

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT This is very strange. I have not clarified that angular material is used. After removing all Angular Material from my code I tried putting it 1:1 and it worked. It really seems to be an issue with Material

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add `type="button"` to the button for the clear.
If there is not type on the button, Angular seems to see it as a submit button and try to submit the form, thus executing the function linked to the button.

Comment: Why did this fix the issue? Do you have any further explanation or documentation to show maybe?

Comment: I've edit the answer, but my understanding of it is mainly through test-and-trial and some finding through SO. I'll edit again if I find more reliable sources.